# Is it possible to directly go to the transit area with self printed boarding pass while travelling with two different airlines?

Tags: tickets, airport-transfer

I will be traveling from A to C, and I will have a connection at B.
I will use two distinct airlines and I have 9 hours between my flights . 
9 hours is a long time and I can't entertain myself out of transit area (most of the cafes and the lounge is there).

I was wondering if it's possible to print the second boarding pass (the one i use from point B to C) online by myself and directly go to the transit area?

Comment: Typically you cannot get your boarding pass before check-in opens. Once your boarding pass becomes available, typically nothing will prevent you from proceeding. Note that for international flights where they will do visa checks etc, usually that is done at check in so you will usually have to wait till check in opens.

Comment: A lot depends on _which airport_ B is. Different airports are set up differently. Does it _have_ a transit area? Do you need to "enter" that transit area specifically, or is it simply where you find yourself when you disembark from your incoming flight? What are the security/immigration arrangements at that airport for your pair of flights? Do you have checked baggage to transfer? Do you have a single booking (yes, that is possible even on different airlines) or separate tickets? We have no way of knowing as long as you just call them A, B, C.

Comment: I'm going to Istanbul Ataturk airport from Tehran by an Iranian airline and then will go to Croatia by Turkish airlines . I bought the tickets separetly and I don't have a single ticket . Last year I booked a single ticket from Turkish airlines and had no problem transiting in that airport . I also have no baggage to transfer which makes it lot more easier. But I'm a 16 year old girl that will travel solo and also haven't ever used an e -boarding pass or a printed one thus am a bit nervous about the situation .Will I be able to directly go to transit instead of waiting 9h till check in opens?

Answer (score 3):

Noone asks for the *incoming* boarding pass to compare with your *outgoing* boarding pass and makes decisions based on the similarities between the two. It would be an absolute zoo: you might have a single ticket on two airlines, you might have a single ticket which you think is on a single airline but in fact they are on different operating carriers, you might have two tickets on the same airline and who knows what else combinations are possible given there are no less than three different kinds of carriers (ticketing, marketing and operating). Not to mention that some passengers create, ahem, what to call what some of us do? ... interesting ;) flight itineraries.

No, having the outgoing boarding pass is enough. Online check in typically opens a lot earlier (at least 24 hours but sometimes days or even months) so having an electronic or self printed boarding pass is not at all unusual at nine hours before flight.

There are two possible problems: a) there is no online check in. I do not think you want to fly that airline in 2017 so I will skip this case. I mean, Yakutia have introduced online checkin in 2014 December and it's really, really hard to find a more remote corner of the world than the one they fly. b) if the tickets are not on the same day. Depends on where you transfer and how but if you need to cross security or border guard then they you typically need a same day boarding pass although nighttime flights are sometimes exceptions -- basically, you need to give us more details if the two tickets are on different days if you want us to help.

Comment: Smartwings (Czech company) only does online check-in for flights departing from Prague. Otherwise you're stuck for a physical check-in.

Comment: As I mentioned "I do not think you want to fly that airline". You just made the case for at least me not wanting to fly Smartwings. If OP has the bad luck (and lack of research) to be on such an airline then they will let us know and we will discuss that then.

Comment: There are many, many situations where you can can't check-in online (or you can, but won't get the boarding pass) even if the airline usually allows it, depending on the airport, the destination, the airline, whether the traveller has checked bags, their nationality, etc.

Comment: I'm going to Istanbul Ataturk airport from Tehran by an Iranian airline and then will go to Croatia by Turkish airlines . I bought the tickets separetly and I don't have a single ticket . Last year I booked a single ticket from Turkish airlines  and had no problem transiting in that airport . I also have no baggage to transfer which makes it lot more easier. But I'm a 16 year old girl that will travel solo and also haven't ever used an e -boarding pass or a printed one thus am a bit nervous about the situation .Will I be able to directly go to transit instead of waiting 9h till check in opens?

Comment: By the way,my flights aren't overnight

Comment: This information would've been very useful in the original question. I will presume you are an Iranian citizen in which case you need a visa to Croatia and it's extremely likely TK won't allow online checkin but it's not clear, their website says "Passport-Visa checks are controlled at the time of check-in and during boarding.". You should ask a new question: Does Turkish Airlines allow Iranian citizens to check in online when flying to Croatia? If you are not an Iranian citizen then, of course, put your citizenship in there.

Comment: If I manage to check in online , Won't I have any problems during boarding with printed boarding pas? The website says: "During boarding, only the original boarding pass printed via our web site will be accepted. Fax and other copies will not be accepted." Can you explain what it means?